# How to reposition image added by attribute text , on product description page?

Tags: magento-2.1

I added a image using Attribute

> Store->attribute->product

and its text type and its name is

```
add_text_area
```

It's showing on the admin side and I can upload an image using WYSIWYG. And it's showing like this 
[image]

And I added on product page creating a new phtml file

> Magneto_Catalog/templates/product/view/topattributes.phtml

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_customAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('add_text_area');
$_customAttributeValue = $_customAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<p>Add Text Area: <?php echo $_customAttributeValue; ?></p>
```

And my xml call in `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="product.info.main"> 
</block>
```

then I added it in `catalog_product_view.xml` file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<!-- 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
--> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<body> 

<referenceContainer name="content" > 
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="product.info.main"> 
</block> 
<block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-"> </block> 
<container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 

<!-- Static blocks --> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 




</referenceContainer> 

<!-- Reset attributes of main containers --> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" before="-" /> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" after="product.info.main" /> 

<!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper --> 
<move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 

<!-- Move some blocks to new positions --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> --> 
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> 

<!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file --> 
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 

<!-- Product collateral data (tabs) --> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" template="Infortis_Base::product/view/details.phtml" > 
<arguments> 
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument> 
<argument name="show_tabs" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::showTabs" /> 


</arguments> 



<!-- Custom static blocks as tabs --> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block1" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab1</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab1</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab2</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab2</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceBlock> 

<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" > 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" /> 


</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getUpsellProductsTemplate" /> 
<!-- TODO: --> 
<argument name="is_responsive" xsi:type="string">false</argument> 
<argument name="show_items" xsi:type="string">3</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 

<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Infortis_Base::product/list/slider.phtml</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 

<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/> 
<!-- <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.details" after="-"/> --> 


<!-- <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper"> 
<container name="extra.product.view" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="extra.product.view" > 
<container name="extra.product.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-product-detail-section"> 

</container> 
</container> 
</referenceContainer> 


<move element="product.info.details" destination="extra.product.view.container" /> --> 



</body> 
</page>
```

After doing this image is coming on top of the page before product image. I want it to appear before tabs of description of product .

Comment: where is topattributes.phtml , in XML I don't see you called it anywhere.....got it

Comment: @ManojDeswal  this block on start of page     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="product.info.main"> 
</block>

Comment: @ManojDeswal   I gave destination destination="main.content" after="-" . And its at the end of page . I want to appear it before tabs and related products

Comment: Try , the way I posted code , may be this help you... as I can't replicate it so not sure but should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put below code in the end of your `XML` file, and remove your code you added in the top.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="-"/>      
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: mean  just before body tag I should post this ?

Comment: yes , as we did for reviews tab ...after this you can '<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/> '

Comment: let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: work like a charm bro :D  . manoj bro I have made this attribute using admin panel and by putting its type text . And enabled a wysiwyg editor . But When I upload a image using it , it gave broken link ?  But When I only post code like this   <p><img src="http://localhost/sitespy/pub/media/wysiwyg/ShopLanding-Banner.jpg" alt="" /></p>   it works .

Comment: and thank you :) this solution worked for me

Comment: it sounds great !

Comment: can you come in chat for few minutes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66185/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-learner).

Comment: bro you have few minutes ?

Comment: hello... how can I help you

Comment: can you come to chat ?