# How to set two page layout in category page?

Tags: layout, xml, magento-2.1.7, page-layouts

I using a theme in **Magento 2.1.7**. In my category page I am having 2-column-left layout with this I am getting this look of my category page given in the

Image-1

[image]

I want this look in my category page given in Image-2

[image]

Where I need to change for this? If I am changing in my `1 column page_layout` then it is **affecting my home page also**. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194216/how-to-add-an-image-before-breadcrumb-on-specific-page/194252?noredirect=1#comment268655_194252)

Please add below code in your **`Layout Update Xml`** section of your category settings in admin panel.

```
 <move element="your.static.block.name" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs"/>
```

Create static block and add image, don't forget to change the element attribute value with the value of your block name.

Comment: if this help you dont forgot to mark as accepted answer so it will help other too.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer for the proper understanding of layout `.xml` file & how it is working

Go to the **`catalog_category_view.xml`** file in your own theme at the location **`magento_root\app\design\frontend\Package\themename\Magento_Catalog\layout`** & add the below code because it is working with the both the below given code

**Code 1**

```
<move element="your.static.block.name" destination="page.top" before="-"/>
```

**Code 2**

```
<move element="your.static.block.name" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs"/>
```

> Note: If you are not able to see the changes run the below command
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```
>
> - Make sure whatever changes you wanted put it in last of the .xml file before `</page>`
> - If you are using a third party theme then for your changes make your custom theme & inherit that third party theme so that you can
>     update your third party theme regularly & easily without trouble