# How to add a image after breadcrumb for inner pages Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

How to add a image after breadcrumb for inner pages ? I use this link but it doesn't work for me [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194216/how-to-add-an-image-before-breadcrumb-on-specific-page)

[image: mag]

Comment: you can create a widget in admin for show specific block where you will insert image then set widget layout position where you want to call.

Comment: or add in xml file to  <move element="your.static.block.name" destination="page.top" after="breadcrumbs"/>